# User input countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get undefined and NaN returned when pressing start. 
The user should be able to input numbers and the countdown will start from the input. Could appreciate some help :)

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Timer.js"></script>
    <title>Uppgift2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frm">
        Seconds:
        <input type="text" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="0" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnct" value="Input" />
    </form>
    <span id="timespan"></span>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="countdown()">
    <p id="para"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript/$:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnct').click(function () {
        var CCOUNT = $('#seconds').val();
        $("#para").text(CCOUNT);
    });
});
var t, count;

function cddisplay() {
    document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = count;
}

function countdown() {
    cddisplay();
    if (count === 1) {
    } else {
        count--;
        t = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `count` doesn't have a value when you call `cddisplay`?

Comment: Why all these downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with your code.

#### 1. count was always undefined.

You never initialized count. and You had two variables in code. Kept the value in CCOUNT and dint pass it to the actual `count` which was used in the counter.

#### 2. count value obtained in `#btnct` click was a local variable

So when you initialized `CCOUNT` with the obtained value, `CCOUNT` is a local variable which cant be accessed outside the listener function. So better to make it global so that you can access it from the other functions you have defined.

#### 3. `.val()` returns a string and you need to convert it to int

In your code you are directly using the value obtained via `.val()` method. Which would be a string and messes up the calculation when you perform decrement straight on it. Instead you have to convert it to int using `parseInt`.

#### 4. Using a namespace.

Instead using the global scope. You can refer on how to make a namespace and organize your code sothat it will free you from conflicts with other existing code when you application code increases. Even you can move the `cddisplay`,`countdown`, `t`, `count` to `document.ready's` lister function scope sothat it wont pollute the global scope as Dipen Bagia shown in his answer.

```
var t, count;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnct').click(function () {
        count = parseInt($('#seconds').val(),10);
        $("#para").text(count);
    });
});


function cddisplay() {
    document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = count;
}

function countdown() {
    cddisplay();
    if (count === 1) {
    } else {
        count--;
        t = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    }
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p6umwb22/1/)

Comment: +1, but you should really always use a radix value with parseInt - `parseInt(n, 10)`

Comment: Could you please explain why exactly was this downvoted?

Comment: I sense some butt-hurt.  There's lots of down-voting that makes no sense.

Comment: he has downvoted all the posts on this page i guess. :D

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Rob. Here is the working code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnct').click(function () {
            var CCOUNT = $('#seconds').val();
            $("#para").text(CCOUNT);
        });
    });
    var t, count = 0;

    function cddisplay() {
        document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = count;
          if (count === 1) {
        } else {
            count--;
            t = setTimeout(cddisplay, 1000);
        }
    }

    function countdown() {
        count = $('#seconds').val();
        cddisplay();

    }
```